# How Do Payments Occur for Reactivated PayPal Recurring Profiles?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Consider the following scenario. A PayPal recurring profile is set to bill Smith $10 on the 6th of each month.

In April, Smith's credit card expires and the recurring profile is automatically suspended.

Smith then lets his subscription lapse for a few months.

Then on September 25th he reactivates the profile (either through his PayPal account or my website via API).

Will I receive the payment of $10 immediately upon the reactivation, and a new schedule will be automatically set up to bill Smith on the 25th of each month, or will he be charged only on October 6th, as per the original schedule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [PayPal Payments Standard development guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/), it indicates that by default if the subscription payment fails, PayPal will try again 3 days later, then a final attempt 5 days after that. If all three attempts fail, then the subscription is canceled.

The subscription is not suspended, so if the customer comes back several months later, they will be setting up a new profile, so you would receive the $10 on Sept 25, and the new billing cycle will be the 25th.

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is a txn_type = recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment, so I thought a credit card failure would cause the profile to be suspended rather than canceled.

There is some contradictory documentation here, but suppose the profile gets suspended for _any_ reason. Same question: will reactivating it months later produce an immediate payment or will the old schedule resume?

Comment: Hi, Have you found any solution? I have one more issue related I am using Paypal sandbox, Facing an issue with the PayPal subscription webhook when the installment is failed to deduct due to some reasons like cc expired etc so i am not getting a webhook call for Billing Subscription Suspended as this event is in the list of PayPal webhook event documents, please help me if have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the subscription was suspended by you (the seller) and then reactivated later, then it will resume on the next scheduled payment attempt. If the subscription is suspended by PayPal due to failed payment attempts then it cannot be reactivated.

Here is a little more information on payments that are failing from PayPal's Documentation:

1. To avoid overlapping payments, there are no reattempts if another payment for the same subscription is scheduled within 14 days of the failed payment.
2. If a payment fails, notification emails are sent to both you and your subscriber.

Comment: For the point 1, will the next payment have the outstanding amount of the previous failed payment ?
What will happen to the failed payment ? Can the system implement Paypal's recurring payment consider this case as a skipped payment ?